# Is there a way to hide some events from an Outlook calendar?

Tags: iphone, ms-office, calendar

I have an Outlook calendar synced to my iPhone which has a lot of "reminders" that I don't really want to see on my actual calendar.  How can I hide *some* of these items from my iPhone, without deleting them entirely from Outlook?

Comment: Isn't there an option to deselect (hide) calendars in the iCal app?

Comment: Yes, I can enable and disable specific calendars.  But this is about specific items in a calendar; my work calendar.

Comment: Make the Items PRIVATE  so it wont share!

Comment: @Buscar웃 - Setting a calendar item as private in Outlook does not prevent it from showing up in the iPhone's calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You can move those items you don't want to view in your phone into a new 'reminders' calendar, then disable that in your phone, however this has the shortcoming that other staff in our org do not see the free/busy information of that 'reminders' calendar. If I could fix that problem this would work for me.

related question: https://superuser.com/questions/636605/how-do-i-share-free-busy-info-from-an-outlook-subcalendar